# Integrating JPCT-AE with Vuforia

Tags: android, rendering, vuforia, jpct

I am Integrating JPCT-AE with Vuforia for as Vuforia sample `ImageTarget` teapot model. I followed the kelmar and Sam Rad's [answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/15199479/jpct-ae-vuforia/15227205#15227205) and now I am able to render my model as well as teapot but in landscape mode only.

:::::BUT:::::::

When I make changes in `initApplication()` in ImageTarget

```
int screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR; 
                                        or  ORIENTATION_PORTRATE;
```

My model starts rendering here and there on the screen which means it's not the way that teapot is rendered. As I understand, we need to change the matrix something to render model in portrait mode.

But I don't know how. If you have any idea, please refer me shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote from Vuforia sample code:

```
Set the screen orientation
        //
        // NOTE: It is recommended to set this because of the following reasons:
        //
        //    1.) Before Android 2.2 there is no reliable way to query the
        //        absolute screen orientation from an activity, therefore using 
        //        an undefined orientation is not recommended. Screen 
        //        orientation matching orientation sensor measurements is also
        //        not recommended as every screen orientation change triggers
        //        deinitialization / (re)initialization steps in internal QCAR 
        //        SDK components resulting in unnecessary overhead during 
        //        application run-time.
        //
        //    2.) Android camera drivers seem to always deliver landscape images
        //        thus QCAR SDK components (e.g. camera capturing) need to know 
        //        when we are in portrait mode. Before Android 2.2 there is no 
        //        standard, device-independent way to let the camera driver know 
        //        that we are in portrait mode as each device seems to require a
        //        different combination of settings to rotate camera preview 
        //        frames images to match portrait mode views. Because of this,
        //        we suggest that the activity using the QCAR SDK be locked
        //        to landscape mode if you plan to support Android 2.1 devices
        //        as well. Froyo is fine with both orientations.
```

I have read on [Changing Screen.orientation at Runtime](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/changing-screenorientation-runtime) that screen height and width do not change if you switch the orientation. They stay the same as default orientation which results to malformed tracking.

Personally, I don't think that you get a good result if you change the orientation but in order to make sure you can ask from Vuforia [support](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum). team. Check it for yourself to see whether screen height and width change during orientation switch or not. If so, you may create your `FrameBuffer` with new values which I believe will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for reply , i go the point . as i asked to vuforia moderator AlessandroB , he also reply : Vuforia axis system are somehow defined in landscape mode. and told swap the X & Y  axis and set it in JPCT camera object. but i don't understand where i will get the axis and where i have to set . if u did it then please tell me some clue . this is the vuforia commu link ...  https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/integrating-jpct-ae-vuforia

Comment: @ashunkhs, Sorry I didn't do that because I didn't need portrait mode. Why do you even need portrait? What is your intention?

Comment: actually my app is in portrait mode . i can't change its UI design. So i need to change it as my app.

Comment: thanks Sam ..i got it .thanks for your help. now its working in portrait mode also.

Comment: @ashunkhs, Glad to hear that. You may post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it. It may be useful for future visitors. Also, I suggest to change the question title to `Vuforia and jPCT in portrait` or something more descriptive like that.